# Pseudo Code java Arrays

Tags: java, pseudocode

I have a pseudo code to implement in Java, however I'm doing something wrong, here's the task and what I have so far:

- The pseudo code:

> Algoritm `ArrayMax(arr)`
>
> Input: A 1-D numerical array Arr of size n>0.
>
> 1. Let CurrentMax = Arr^0
> 2. For i=1 to n-1
> 3. If Arr^i > CurrentMax Then CurrentMax = Arr^i
> 4. End For
>
> Output: CurrentMax, the largest value in Arr

- The instructions:

> We are going to implement and test algoritm `ArrayMax(arr)`.
>
> The following code snipper can be used as basis for your work
>
> ```
> public static void main(String args[]){
>     double arr[]= {1,-6.3,9000,1.1,0.0,-456,6,23,-451.88};
>     System.out.println(ArrayMax(arr));
> }
>
> public static double ArrayMax(double arr[]){
>     double CurrentMax = arr[0];
>     // Complete the algorithm here...
>     return(CurrentMax);
> }
> ```
>
> Test your work on a number of different input datasets.
>
> Finally create a new version of your program that works with an `ArrayList`

Here is what I have done:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CS1702_65 {

    public static double ArrayMax(double arr[]){
        double CurrentMax = arr[0];
        for(i = 1;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > CurrentMax){
                CurrentMax = arr[i];
            }

        }
        return(CurrentMax);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       // System.out.print("Enter a 1D numerical array Arr of size n>0:     ");
       // int x = input.nextInt();

        double arr[]= {1,-6.3,9000,1.1,0.0,-456,6,23,-451.88};
        System.out.println(ArrayMax(arr));
    }

}
```

Comment: please include the `Task` and the `Pseudo` as text inside the question (Text wont get invalid, Links on the other side can get invalid). Also you might want to say where you´re stuck. You´re getting an exception, a compiler error or a wrong result maybe. You want us to help you, so help us to understand how we can help you :)

Comment: There is a typo, it is `return CurrentMax;` .

Comment: also, `n`, as used for the loop condition, isn´t defined anywhere and i guess you want `arr.length`, and `i` is missing it´s class type, as of `int i...` here

Comment: @Berger shouldn´t be a problem with the paranthesis surrounding there or?

Comment: @KevinEsche : well indeed it is okay to have the returned values inside parenthesis , `return (CurrentMax);` also works .

Answer (score 1):

You have bad implementation of ArrayMax, you forget initial variables "i" and "n".
Here you have properly function:

```
    public static double ArrayMax(double arr[]){
      double CurrentMax = arr[0];
      int n = arr.length;
      for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){
         if (arr[i] > CurrentMax){
            CurrentMax = arr[i];
         }
      }
      return CurrentMax;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maxOfArray(T[] arr){
    if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
        T max = arr[0];
        for (int index = 1; index < arr.length; index++) {
            if (max.compareTo(arr[index]) < 0) {
                max = arr[index];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Double maxOfArray = maxOfArray(new Double[]{1D, 1.1, 3D});
    System.out.println("maxOfArray = " + maxOfArray);
}
```